# Consulta resumen con joins y agregados

Tags: sql, join, agregación

Quizás me podáis ayudar a hacer una consulta del modo mas elegante y optimizado (rendimiento) posible, si es posible en una sola consulta.

**"Clientes que tienen préstamos y depósitos en una misma sucursal, y por cada uno de ellos el número de préstamos y cuentas que tiene, así como la suma total depositada y prestada."**

Tablas:

```
* Cliente (Id PK, Nombre)
* Sucursal (Id PK, Nombre)
* Deposito (Num_Cta PK, Saldo, Id_cli FK, Id_Suc FK)
* Prestamo (N_Prest PK, Cantidad, Id_cli FK, Id_Suc FK)
```

Mi mejor consulta es esta, pero seguramente existe una mejor forma de hacerlo, idealmente tal vez quitando los select dentro del select, y en cualquier caso mejorando el rendimiento.

```
select c.nombre, 
       count(distinct n_prest) as "Nº préstamos", 
       count(distinct d.num_cta) as "Nº cuentas", 
       (select sum(saldo) from deposito d2 where d2.id_cli=c.id) as "Total saldos", 
       (select sum(cantidad) from prestamo p2 where p2.id_cli=c.id) as "Total prestado"
from deposito d natural join prestamo p 
inner join cliente c on d.id_cli = c.id
inner join sucursal s on d.id_suc = s.id
group by c.id
order by c.nombre;
```

El código para crear y poblar una bdd de prueba (con H2), [aquí](https://mega.nz/file/Z59xzIhA#AshpkkTh5sTk2_YCPPrPtHzo38eMBdQAKHNnjjjcn0Q).

[image: El resultado de la consulta debería ser este:]

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando quieres hacer conteos o agregados de 2 tablas distintas, lo mejor es hacerlo antes de unirlas a la tabla a la que hacen referencia.

Vamos pensando con un poco de lógica, lo primero que necesitas son los clientes y por eso tiene que ser tu tabla inicial. Luego necesitas el conteo de prestamos por cliente y sucursal, así como de cuentas por cliente y sucursal. Cada uno se hace de manera independiente para poder hacer el join con cliente. En el ejemplo, puse también la tabla sucursal por si necesitas datos de ahí, pero en realidad no hace falta según el planteamiento del problema y los resultados que muestras.

```
SELECT c.ID, 
       c.NOMBRE AS NombreCliente, 
       s.NOMBRE AS NombreSucursal, 
       d.Cuentas, 
       p.Prestamos, 
       Saldos, 
       Prestado
FROM CLIENTE c
JOIN (SELECT id.ID_CLI, 
            id.ID_SUC, 
            COUNT( NUM_CTA) AS Cuentas,
            SUM( SALDO)     AS Saldos
      FROM DEPOSITO id 
      GROUP BY id.ID_CLI, 
               id.ID_SUC) d ON c.ID = d.ID_CLI
JOIN (SELECT ip.ID_CLI, 
            ip.ID_SUC, 
            COUNT(*)      AS Prestamos,
            SUM(CANTIDAD) AS Prestado
        FROM PRESTAMO ip 
        GROUP BY ip.ID_CLI, 
                 ip.ID_SUC) p ON c.ID = p.ID_CLI 
                             AND d.ID_SUC = p.ID_SUC
JOIN SUCURSAL s ON d.ID_SUC = s.ID;
```

Comment: implementar los joins esta bien, sin embargo la idea consiste en eliminar los **select** internos

Comment: Cualquier propuesta es bienvenida, supongo que hay varias formas de hacerla. La dificultad está efectivamente en quitar los selects anidados, si es posible. Pero lo que prima es el rendimiento, así que la mejor consulta es la que tenga mejor rendimiento.

Comment: @DavElsanto ¿Por qué habría que eliminarlos? ¿Qué propones?

Comment: Ese el propósito eliminar los `select,` puedes hacer un `join` entre `deposito` y `préstamo`.

Comment: @DavElsanto ¿Puedes proponer una consulta como respuesta? La consulta que yo propongo en la pregunta hace ese join, pero ya luego no se como quitarme los selects anidados. No sé si existe esa solución.

Comment: En eso estoy ``

Comment: Si se hace un join directo, se pueden obtener datos equivocados. Por eso se hace el agregado antes del join.

Comment: @Luis Cazares, así es, en el archivo que comparto viene comentado el select original que puede dar malos resultados. Se duplican las tuplas. Concretamente hay un cliente con dos préstamos y dos cuentas, el join da 4 tuplas y por tanto las suma agregada está mal.

Answer (score 0):

Aca la respuesta utilizando unicamente `joins`, sim embargo hago uso de una tabla temporal por si te interesa.

```sql
create temporary table result as
select
c.nombre as 'Nombre',
p.N_Prest as 'Prestamos',
d.Num_Cta as 'Cuentas',
d.Saldo as 'Saldos',
p.Cantidad as 'Prestado'
from Prestamo p
inner join Deposito d on p.Id_cli = d.Id_cli
inner join Cliente c on p.Id_cli = c.id
inner join Sucursal s on p.Id_Suc = s.id
group by p.N_Prest, d.Num_Cta
order by c.nombre;

select * from result;

select 
n.Nombre,
n.Prestamos,
count(n.Nombre) as 'Cuentas', 
sum(n.Prestado) as 'Total Prestado',
sum(n.Saldos) as 'Total de saldos'
from (
  select 
  m.Nombre, 
  count(m.Nombre) as 'Prestamos', 
  m.Cuentas,
  sum(m.Saldos) as 'Saldos',
  m.Prestado as 'Prestado'
  from (
    select 
      Nombre,
      count(Cuentas) as 'Cuentas',
      Saldos,
      Prestado
      from result
      group by Nombre, Cuentas, Saldos, Prestado
      ) as m
      group by m.Nombre, m.Cuentas, m.Prestado

    ) as n
  group by n.Nombre, n.Cuentas, n.Prestamos;
  
  
  drop temporary table result;
```

y por si quieres ver el código completo:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dmqwS1PxVGQvrmXHQyTVzh/16

Comment: No solo estás dando una alternativa más costosa que además utiliza código no estándar. También el resultado es incorrecto.

Comment: Por qué dices eso??? Has realizado su consultas en consultas con millones de registros???

Comment: Porque estás leyendo todos los datos de la tabla original, escribiendo a una tabla nueva y leyendo de esa tabla nueva. Pero antes de enfocarte en mejorar el rendimiento, es importante revisar que los datos sean correctos y desgraciadamente no lo son.